# Django REST on Heroku with Server Error (500)

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I made my django website RESTful, but i can only see the endpoint when debug=True. When I switch to false it gives an Server Error (500). The app is deployed on heroku.
I tried to use different permissions as "AllowAny" and "IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly" in views.py and added them also in settings.py under REST_FRAMEWORK.
Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Comment: Usually it's about `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. But as @Chris said, it can be anything serverside